# ajax make responseText to be an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to get ajax answer as DOM object.

This is my code:

```
$.ajax(URL, {
    async: false,
    complete: function(e){
        code = $(e.responseText);
        alert( code.find('body').length );
    }
});
```

So I need to make response as an object and then make selection in it.

But in previous sample my Firebug returns:

```
Object[<TextNode textContent="\n\n \n ">, title, <TextNode textContent="\n">, meta, <TextNode textContent="\n">, meta, <TextNode textContent="\n">, meta, <TextNode textContent="\n">, meta, <TextNode textContent="\n">, meta, <TextNode textContent="\n">
```

---

For example, this code works fine:

```
$.get(URL, function(e){
    var code = $(e);
    alert( code.find('body').length );
});
```

But I need to make async request, so $.get is not an option (or I can't find solution with it).

Thanks for advise!

Comment: Read http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ `$.get()` is a shorthand for `$.ajax()` So __$.get is surely an option__. Did you tried `code = $(e);` in `$.ajax()`?

Comment: You mean you need synchronous ajax call since you have async: false?

Comment: If you need "*Sjax*," forgoing the asynchronous default, then you'll have to use `$.ajax({ async: false })`. `$.get()` doesn't offer a way to specify a synchronous request that blocks until the response arrives.

Comment: When I'm trying to use code = $(e) - Firebug returns: `Object[Object { readyState=4, responseText="<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-... \n \n </body>\n</html>", status=200, more...}]`

Comment: The `async = false` will only execute the request synchronously. you need to set it as true(which is the default value for async) to execute an request as asynchronously. And try success call back as you are doing in `$.get` example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that I found at this moment is to make returned data as html and then it will able to manipulate with it. My working example is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    async: false,
    type : "get",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data){
        var response = $('<html/>').html(data);
        alert(response.find('#ELEM').length);
    }
});
```

So, as you can see - I made response data to be HTML and it helps me to use `.find()` and other helpful things.

Hope this solution will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax code is not correct that should be something like this and you can get the response in the success callback instead:

```
$.ajax({
   url:URL,
   type : "get", 
   dataType: "html", // expected output from the requested url
   success: function(e){
      code = $(e.responseText); // or try with $(e) only
      alert( code.find('body').length );
   }, 
   error: function(err){
      alert(err.responseText);
   }
});
```

Comment: No, the problem is same. I tried to do like you said, and alert returns 0 (like there is no `body`) and firebug returns `Object[<TextNode textContent="\n\n \n ">, title, <TextNode textContent="\n">, ........`